# How can I change the theme of the xib files editor in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, editor, xib

I can make Xcode's text editor to dark using Xcode preferences.

How can I change the xib files editor theme?

[image: code editor with dark colors]

[image: Interface Builder]

Answer (score 1):

The editor is called the **Interface Builder** and, as per now, you **cannot change** the look of it.